# has_term not working

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I've been scratching my head all day with this one. I'm trying to use `has_term` but it just won't work. I do get this notice but I'm not 100% sure it's related. I've also tried `is_object_in_term()` but that doesn't seem to do anything in this case.

> Notice: Undefined property: `stdClass::$object_id` in
>   `/wp-includes/taxonomy.php` on line 3613

```
if( has_term('past-attendees', 'speakercategory' ) ): 
    echo 'test'; 
endif;

if(is_object_in_term( $post->ID, 'speakercategory', 'past-attendees' ) ):
    echo 'test'; 
endif;
```

`wp_get_object_terms()` does return the term so I can't get my head around why the above two examples didn't work. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get this in a vanilla 4.4 install? Where are you testing this?

Comment: What happens if you pass the `$post` object into the `has_term` as the last parameter, do you get the correct result?

Comment: @birgire Not really, it's a custom theme, has a handful of plugins installed.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Same thing when I pass $post. The variable is defined right before that call.

Comment: Did you check if `$post` is not empty? To me looks like `$post->ID` is null, that's why you are getting the notice message when using `is_object_in_term()`.
Can you share the result for `var_export($post);` ?

Answer (score 1):

You mention in a previous comment that you are defining `$post` directly before the conditional statements. Since this is the case you *need* to pass the `$post` object to both these functions to get desired results otherwise WordPress will attempt to use the `global $post` object which isn't what you've defined and thus throwing errors or unexpected results.

Parameter three for [`has_term( $term, $taxonomy, $post )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) says:

> **$post**
>   ([integer|object](https://codex.wordpress.org/How_to_Pass_Tag_Parameters#Integer.7Cobject)) (optional) Post to check **instead of the current post**.
>   Default: **null**